# The same Spring APP behaves different when loading security core module?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an Springboot WAR file. When I start it on two different machine it behaves differently.

On good machine, it has this info in the log:

```
11:45:29.289 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.a.f.i.c.b.WarWebApplicationInitializer - Running with Spring Boot v2.2.4.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.3.RELEASE
11:45:29.293 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.f.i.c.b.WarWebApplicationInitializer - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: basicauth
11:45:36.709 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.s.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - You are running with Spring Security Core 5.2.1.RELEASE
11:45:36.712 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.s.c.SecurityNamespaceHandler - Spring Security 'config' module version is 5.2.1.RELEASE
11:45:36.725 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.s.c.m.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser - Expressions were enabled for method security but no SecurityExpressionHandler was configured. All hasPermision() expressions will evaluate to false.
```

Run it on bad machine, it gives:

```
10:41:10.904 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.a.f.i.c.b.WarWebApplicationInitializer - Running with Spring Boot v2.2.4.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.3.RELEASE
10:41:10.907 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.f.i.c.b.WarWebApplicationInitializer - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: basicauth
10:41:31.948 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:99)
```

My question here is what's the procedure Spring uses to load the security module? It seems to me in the bad case, the application failed to find library locally and try it online? Is that so?

Later in the bad log, I see this:

```
10:41:31.984 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 35 in XML document from URL [file:/bitnami/tomcat/data/fineract-provider/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/appContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 35; columnNumber: 36; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'sec:global-method-security'.
```

I guess this is due to the fact that xsd access failed.

Comment: What is good and bad machine?

Comment: are you running app from an IDE?

Comment: I use "good" and "bad" just for the sake of simplicity. Actually they both Debian 9. The difference is that good one use wifi connection, the bad one use cable ethernet. I just don't see that would cause any significant difference. I wonder does Spring always load the xsd file when it starts?

Comment: I am not running it from IDE. I run it from docker images. But the same WAR file.